Difference between polyethylene sulfonate and Nafion?
Nafion is a cation-exchange membrane that I would like to build a chlor-alkali cell, but unfortunately it's crazy expensive(and comes in ridiculously large sizes). Its functional group, the sulfonate ion, allows cations to move across the membrane. However, sodium polyacrylate absorbs a lot of water(allowing it to form a thick gel) and has an acrylate group at the end. Could this same effect be used to form a cation-exchange membrane?

I think this explanation in the Wikipedia about sums it up: " Nafion has received a considerable amount of attention as a proton conductor for proton exchange membrane (PEM) fuel cells because of its excellent chemical and mechanical stability in the harsh conditions of this application". Those C-F bonds render the polymer resistant to degradation. They give the polymer other unique features as well.
